# "Appear" followed by a verb: Necessarily a copula (linking verb)?

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, copular-verbs

I’m wondering how I can structurally determine when a verb is being used as a copula and when it is not. Specifically, is the verb “appear” followed by a verb NECESSARILY a copula (i.e., linking verb)?

One of my references (“An A-Z of English Grammar & Usage”, Longman, p.271), describes the following pattern for linking verbs:

> > Other patterns typical of linking verbs
>
> (D) SUBJECT + VERB + TO BE + COMPLEMENT

However, I cannot find a source that says that “appear” followed by any verb (such as in the following example) is always a linking verb:

> Sarah appeared to have won.

Answer (score 1):

On the previous page, your reference says that *appear* is a linking verb when the sentence in which it occurs is on either pattern (A) or pattern (B) as shown on page 270, and gives the examples *The children appear happy enough* and *This appeared the only solution*. A footnote points out that the second of those is very rare in American English, where patterns (D) or (E) can be used instead.

I haven’t tested this proposition, but my intuition is that *appear* is a linking verb when it can be replaced by *seem*. It is clearly not a linking verb when used intransitively with the meaning ‘come into view’.